# SKLearn FastICA - How to get the loadings?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

For PCA loadings are calculated by:

```
loadings = pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)
```

For ICA there isn't an .explained_variance_ array, so is it just?:

```
ica.components_[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, be aware that PCA loadings are quite different from whatever you might want to use the ICA "coefficients" for. Examples in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-ica-blind-source-separation-py) provide the code snippets but you need to read the author's [notes](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ensjones/TalkSlides/HyvarinenSlides.pdf) before you proceed.

Briefly `ica.mixing_` gives you the unmixed signal constituents and its pseudo-inverse provides coefficients, in `ica.components_`, applied to the data to obtain these mixture components. (As an abomination of the ICA's purpose I assume you're looking for the mixing bit.)